# PHP Mail() Linux Setup

Tags: linux, php, sendmail

I have an Apache server with php installed on it.  It is a Linux machine running openSUSE v. 11.3.  I have a php script that uses the mail function and I have edited the php.ini file to set the sendmail path to /usr/sbin/sendmail which I believe is correct.  I have also restarted the server so the changes take effect.  I'm now lost on what to do.  Any further direction would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Was your MTA already configured?  What MTA do you have installed?  Many different MTAs provide a sendmail binary for compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the question in here. Just send mail with the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) command. That's it.